# 141. Linked List Cycle not sure why I'm hitting time limit

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to solve leetcode 141. Linked List Cycle. but I'm not sure why I'm hitting time limit for this logic.:( Thank you guys

```js
var hasCycle = function(head) {
    let slow = head;
    let fast = head;
    
    while (fast !== null && fast.next !== null) {
        fast = head.next.next;
        slow = head.next;
        
        if (slow === fast) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are never moving your pointers

```
    while (fast !== null && fast.next !== null) {
        fast = head.next.next;
        slow = head.next;
```

`head` never gets reassigned, so you are constantly assigning the same value to `fast`. As long as `head` has at least 3 valid nodes after it, this code will loop forever.